# Estimate textwidth to adjust divs without javascript

Tags: css, html, noscript

In a generated html-file I have several divs aligned pairwise like

```
<div class="title">Title</div><div>Content</div>
<div class="title">Title</div><div>Content</div>
<div class="title">Title</div><div>Content</div>
```

and to adjust the contents, I use javascript to resize the width of each title

however if javascript is disabled, I want to have a callback to estimate the width with css in a way like `.title { width:1.4em; }` where 1.4 is the maximum title length multiplied with a constant

I know it's not possible to get the exact value, but is there a good estimation for a constant to do this?

also is there a way, to define css-classes in noscript or has css something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). The width here are fixed and so you could calculate your width a priori on the server or manually.

Comment: if i defined the font, I can calculate the maximum width irrespective of monospaced or not; but I don't wanna do that, because it quickly turns the page very ugly in some cases